# How to make a dictionary from a list and a from a list of lists

Tags: python

I Have two list. One contains only single values and the other one contains lists.
The values of the first list are almost always ( but not always) the same of values in 0 position of each list of the list of lists.

```
List1 = [ "abcd", "efg", "hijk"]
List2 = [ ["abcd", "hello", "world"],
          ["efg", "My name's", "Tom"], 
          ["hijk", "I", "Love you"]
```

I want to make a dict with keys from list1 and values from list2:

```
Dict = {"abcd": ["hello", "world"], 
        "efg": ["My name's", "Tom"], 
        "hijk": ["I", "Love you"]}
```

I try to do this but without any satisfactory result:

```
List1= [ "abcd", "efg", "hijk"]
List2= [ ["abcd", "hello", "world"],
         ["efg", "My name's", "Tom"], 
         ["hijk", "I", "Love you"]

dict = {}
i = 0
for element in List2:
    if element[0] == List1[i]:
        zip_iterator = zip(List1[i], element[1:])
        dict.update(zip_iterator)
           
    else:
        print("error")
        print(element[0], List1[i])
    i += 1
print(dict)
```

It doesn't give a Traceback, but a strange output.
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't need `List1` at all; just make a dictionary-comprehension from `List2`:

```
>>> List2= [["abcd","hello", "world"], ["efg", "My name's", "Tom"], ["hijk", "I","Love you"]]
>>> {k: v for k, *v in List2}
{'abcd': ['hello', 'world'], 'efg': ["My name's", 'Tom'], 'hijk': ['I', 'Love you']}
```

Here, `for k, *v in ...` is an advanced form of iterable-unpacking, storing the first element of each sub-list in `k` and the remaining elements in `v`.

If it's not quite that simple, and the keys from `List1` could appear in *any* position of the *corresponding* elements of `List2`, try this nested dictionary- and list-comprehension (note: I shuffled the sub-lists of `List2` to make it more interesting):

```
>>> List1= ["abcd", "efg", "hijk"]
>>> List2= [["abcd","hello", "world"], ["My name's", "efg", "Tom"], ["I","Love you", "hijk"]]
>>> {k: [x for x in v if x != k] for k, v in zip(List1, List2)}
{'abcd': ['hello', 'world'], 'efg': ["My name's", 'Tom'], 'hijk': ['I', 'Love you']}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to keep only the keys in `List1`. See their edit.

Answer (score 1):

In this approach, the first loop is used to determine the key from List1. The nested second loop appends all the values from List2 which isn't the key.

```
List1= ["abcd", "efg", "hijk"]
List2= [["abcd","hello", "world"],["efg", "My name's", "Tom"], ["hijk", "I","Love you"]]

dict1 = {}

for i in range(len(List1)):
    key = List1[i]
    dict1[key] = []
    for j in List2[i]:
        if j!=key:
            dict1[key].append(j)

print(dict1)
```

Comment: Ah since the list is being sliced, the index is important in this case. If the key is not at the 0 index, where would it be in List2?

Comment: Will have to edit it again, didn't know that the key wouldn't always be at the 0 index.

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension and only keep the keys that occur in `List1`:

```
>>> {l[0]:l[1:] for l in List2 if l[0] in List1}
{'abcd': ['hello', 'world'],
 'efg': ["My name's", 'Tom'],
 'hijk': ['I', 'Love you']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> List1= [ "abcd", "efg", "hijk"]
>>> List2= [ ["abcd","hello", "world"],["efg", "My name's", "Tom"], ["hijk", "I","Love you"]]
>>> {List[0]:List[1:] for List in List2}
{'abcd': ['hello', 'world'], 'efg': ["My name's", 'Tom'], 'hijk': ['I', 'Love you']}
```

or

```
>>> {name:[_list for _list in List2 if name == _list[0]][0][1:] for name in List1}
{'abcd': ['hello', 'world'], 'efg': ["My name's", 'Tom'], 'hijk': ['I', 'Love you']}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Key/Value

---

In Python 3.x you can assign a new value to a key, or create a key if it doesn't exist yet, like this:

```
dict[key] = value
```

## Lists

---

You can make a dictionary from two lists like this:

```
if len(list1) == len(list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        dict[list1[i]] = list2[i]
```

## Otherwise

---

You can use dictionary-notation, like this:

```
list_ = # List of lists
for List in list_:
    dictionary = {key: value for key, *value in List}
```

## Check

---

Then, you can ensure if everything was well done like this:

```
>>> list1 == dict.keys()
True
>>> list2 == dict.values()
True
```